# How to store and retrieve Dictionary value types in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, save, nsuserdefaults

I was having trouble storing a Dictionary in the NSUserDefaults, and then I had trouble retrieving the values.  After a failed search on the web, I finally figured it out and so I hope this helps you with this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Define your variables for NSUserDefaults, Dictionary and key:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var myDictionary = Dictionary<String, Int>()
let myKey = "Key"
```

How to save your dictionary:

```
defaults.setObject(myDictionary, forKey: myKey)
```

How to retrieve your dictionary:

```
myDictionary = defaults.dictionaryForKey(myKey) as! Dictionary<String, Int>
```

NOTE: make sure that your data types are the same as the way you set them up.

*** FYI, this is using Xcode 6.3.2

Comment: Note that this only works if the types of the keys and values in your dictionary are all "property list types" (dictionaries, arrays, strings, numbers (integer and float), dates, binary data, and Boolean values). If any of the keys/values in your dictionaries are any type other than one of those, the save to user defaults will fail silently. Your example uses a dictionary of fixed type `[String: Int]` which will always work, but with a dictionary of type `[String: AnyObject]` you can get into trouble with dictionaries that contain unsupported types.